Computing/calculating SSB (sum of squares between clusters) for k-modes
I am trying to calculate metrics for validation/calculation of K-modes performance. I am doing my thesis and I need to group patients from binary variables (diseases) I recently read that SSW and SSB metrics might be appropriate.
I only know how to extract SSW from the kmodes function (here replied K-Modes Cluster Validation), but I have no idea how to calculate SSB (between clusters)...could you give an example of how to calculate it?
Someone replied here, but for K-Means: SSB - Sum of squares between clusters
I can work with Calinski–Harabasz index, if is it not possible to compute it for K-modes
